# About Paypal Subscription, is subscription already activated when 'onApprove' callback?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm integrating Paypal's Subscription into my web service.

I would like to know if a subscription is activated when I receive an "onApprove" callback (Javascript SDK).

This also means whether "onApprove" callback is equivalent to receiving a notification event "BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED" from the webhook.

Thank you.